# Parallel processing within a queue (using Pool within Celery)

Tags: python, parallel-processing, threadpool, multiprocessing, django-celery

I'm using [Celery to queue jobs from a CGI application I made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629147/python-cgi-queue). The way I've set it up, Celery makes each job run one- or two-at-a-time by setting `CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = 1` or `= 2` (so they don't crowd the processor or thrash from memory consumption). The queue works great, thanks to advice I got on StackOverflow.

Each of these jobs takes a fair amount of time (~30 minutes serial), but has an embarrassing parallelizability. For this reason, I was using `Pool.map` to split it and do the work in parallel. It worked great from the command line, and I got runtimes around 5 minutes using a new many-cored chip.

Unfortunately, there is some limitation that does not allow daemonic process to have subprocesses, and when I run the fancy parallelized code within the CGI queue, I get this error:

**AssertionError: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children**

I noticed [other people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974695/python-process-pool-non-daemonic) have [had similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066710/multiprocessing-in-python-with-more-then-2-levels), but I can't find an answer that wouldn't require abandoning `Pool.map` altogether, and making more complicated thread code.

What is the appropriate design choice here? I can easily run my serial jobs using my Celery queue. I can also run my much faster parallelized jobs without a queue. How should I approach this, and is it possible to get what I want (*both* the queue and the per-job parallelization)?

A couple of ideas I've had (some are quite hacky):

- The job sent to the Celery queue simply calls the command line program. That program can use Pool as it pleases, and then saves the result figures & data to a file (just as it does now). 
  **Downside:** I won't be able to check on the status of the job or see if it terminated successfully. Also, system calls from CGI may cause security issues.

  Obviously, if the queue is very full of jobs, I can make use of the CPU resources (by setting CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = 6 or so); this will allow many people to be "at the front of the queue" at once.
  **Downside:** Each job will spend a lot of time at the front of the queue; if the queue isn't full, there will be no speedup. Also, many partially finished jobs will be stored in memory at the same time, using much more RAM.

  Use Celery's @task to parallelize within sub-jobs. Then, instead of setting CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = 1, I would set it to 6 (or however many sub jobs I'd like to allow in memory at a time). 
  **Downside:** First of all, I'm not sure whether this will successfully avoid the "task-within-task" problem. But also, the notion of queue position may be lost, and many partially finished jobs may end up in memory at once.

  Perhaps there is a way to call Pool.map and specify that the threads are non-daemonic? Or perhaps there is something more lightweight I can use instead of Pool.map? This is similar to an approach taken on [another open StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516508/python-multiprocessing-pool-inside-daemon-process). Also, I should note that the parallelization I exploit via Pool.map is similar to linear algebra, and there is no inter-process communication (each just runs independently and returns its result without talking to the others).

  Throw away Celery and use multiprocessing.Queue. Then maybe there'd be some way to use the same "thread depth" for every thread I use (*i.e.* maybe all of the threads could use the same Pool, avoiding nesting)?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a workflow management system (WFMS) that manages

- task concurrency
- task dependency
- task nesting

among other things.

From a very high level view, a WFMS sits on top of a task pool like celery, and submits the tasks which are ready to execute to the pool.  It is also responsible for opening up a nest and submitting the tasks in the nest accordingly.

I've developed a system to do just that.  It's called [pomsets](http://pomsets.org).  Try it out, and feel free to send me any questions.

Comment: Is this similar to Sun Grid Engine? I was hoping to use something from within python. Better yet, I'd love to have someone say what is the right thing (in python) to do in this situation in general.

Comment: I would say that SGE is more like celery, in that they both manage a queue of tasks.  As long as the libraries are available, pomsets can submit to celery, SGE, or any other execution queue.  And pomsets is written in Python, so you can build workflows directly in your Python program.

Comment: The best solution was to create `Celery` jobs and use them to launch other `Celery` jobs. But, ultimately this answer is the closest-- essentially I solved the problem by using `Celery` as the sole WFMS.

Comment: I've put the source code on GitHub  https://github.com/mjpan/pomsets-core

Answer (score 0):

I using a multiprocessed deamons based on Twisted with forking and Gearman jobs query normally.

Try to look at Gearman.

Comment: I don't made this task but thinking that these should do it. 
If you would try - please keep me informed about result.